# Efficiently Backing up Multiple Accounts (gmail, yahoo) from Outlook to PST

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, gmail

Outlook is receiving emails from ~20 different Gmail and Yahoo [IMAP/SMTP] accounts, with my goals being to:

1. Backup emails to a `.pst` for archiving on a hard drive
2. Delete `Inbox` emails from Gmail and Yahoo servers

Currently, I've created a new `.pst` file (on backup date) and subfolders named after the email accounts, I drag and drop all emails from Outlook inboxes to these subfolders, accomplishing #2, then I back up that `.pst` to the hard drive.

- This seems labor-intensive and I foresee searching multiple Outlook `.pst` files as intense if backups are performed every few months

Is there a better way?

Comment: Do so by creating an `archive.pst` for each account, unless you want emails from all Gmail accounts going into the same `.pst` database, and even then it may not work as expected _(you cannot archive different webmail services into the same `archive.pst`, such as archiving Hotmail/Outlook and Gmail webmail accounts into the same `archive.pst`)_. _File_ → _Account Settings_ → _Account Settings_ → _Data Files_ → _Add_ → _File Name:_ `<Gmail1>.archive.pst`; Email Folder view → Highlight folders to archive → Folder View [Ribbon] → _AutoArchive Settings_ → _Move old item to_ `<Gmail1>.archive.pst`

Answer (score 0):

I make sure Outlook creates a PST file (it will also create an OST file).

Make sure all your account databases are in one folder. Outlook tends to do this automatically but check.

Then any time you wish, or to a schedule (I use Sync Back Pro), close Outlook and back up the whole folder. One operation.

Comment: Outlook will never create a `.pst` database for a webmail account unless it's an Exchange account, as `.ost` databases are a mirrored copy of the email server and will rebuild upon every Send/Receive. Why would you close Outlook to archive emails, when this functionality is built into Outlook?

Comment: One can backup OST files. That is why I mentioned both. If you are backing up Outlook files , Outlook must be closed or it will fail.  Local archives can be made with Outlook open but I back these up as well.  I want my Outlook files in case a disk fails.

Comment: Backup `.ost` files to where exactly? You can't import them and there's no point to using paid software to convert them to `.pst` since it will cause massive headaches due to how each operates... Again, `.ost` files are an _exact mirror_ of the email server and are completely rebuilt/re-synced upon a Send/Receive... i.e. `.pst` can house data changes independent to what is contained on the email server, whereas `.ost` can never do so because it's an exact mirror and will always exactly mirror what's on the email server. The correct way to backup emails in Outlook is via an `archive.pst`

Comment: I backup Outlook files (whatever Outlook files are there - in my case PST) to another machine for external and therefore safe backup.

Comment: Webmail accounts use `.ost`; If wanting physical `.ost` backups, safest way to avoid major future headaches is to configure a task that runs a `RoboCopy` script every ≤24hrs _(more than 24hrs and you're risking creating headaches down the line - i.e. double, tripple, quadruple, etc. of the same emails or multiples with different changes)_. For example, I generalized [these](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/tree/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/RoboCopy) from the ones I use to backup my `%UserProfile%\Documents\Microsoft\Outlook` directory once a day _(most important `RoboCopy` paramater is `/Mon:1`)_.

Comment: We are on mildly different pages. I do understand that various Outlook / Mail methodologies do different things. But all Outlook can create some kind of local file. I collect all these in one single folder and back this folder up regularly. Yes, if just OST there are limitations, but you can also archive to a frequent schedule and include archives in the backup. So I was taking a simpler but effective view of the situation.

Comment: I understand your approach, my point is backing up an `.ost` file is pointless if doing so for long term storage _(it's a cache file vs `.pst` being an actual data storage file)_, i.e. `.ost` file is backed up once a week and you eventually export those entries to a `.pst` file, what you'll end up with are multiples of the same emails for every `.ost` you export data from as _all_ `.ost` files are exact cache mirrors of the email server at a specific point in time with changes made to either auto-synced to the other upon Send/Receive - they are not the same as `.pst` files.

Comment: _Cont'd..._ A really good analogy would be copying all files from a Windows directory into the same source directory will result in multiple copies of the file with each copy adding the next sequential number to it's file name. However, if exporting multiple `.ost` files from the same account to a `.pst`, it doesn't rename them with a numeral, it's multiple copies of the same email with the same name and it will cause a massive headache if you have to search through each multiple to find the one with the most recent changes _(I'm speaking from experience)_

Answer (score 0):

According to my tests, if you configure multiple email accounts in an Outlook profile at the same time, you can configure the [Outlook Autoarchive](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/830119/description-of-the-autoarchive-feature-in-outlook) function and set different archive pst for different email accounts to meet your needs like below. Personally, I think this is the most convenient method.

[image]
[image]